# Which SSH config option stops me from SSH'ing through a SSH tunnel?

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to connect directly to a my work computer (**work**) which is only available via an outside server (**outside**).

So, the network path is:  home » outside » work

Ideally, this should work:

```
home$ ssh -f -N -L2222:work.example.com:22 outside.example.com
home$ ssh localhost -p 2222  ## This just hangs
```

It doesn't, though.  I can also replace work.example.com with an entirely different server, with the same result.  The steps are correct, because I can use the same logic to connect to the **work** host's web server:

```
home$ ssh -f -N -L10080:work.example.com:80 outside.example.com
home$ lynx http://localhost:10080/  ## work's pretty web page is displayed
```

Also, I can SSH to **work** if I log into **outside** first:

```
home$ ssh outside.example.com
outside$ ssh work.example.com
work$  ## Yay, success!
```

Finally, this also works in a scenario with different servers involved:

```
home$ ssh -f -N -L2222:different.example.com:22 another.example.com
home$ ssh localhost -p 2222
different$  ## Success!
```

So, I guess there's some SSH configuration on **outside** that stops me from using the direct approach, since this works with different servers.

**Home** runs OpenBSD 4.6 with OpenSSH_5.3. **Outside** runs MacOSX 10.7.2 with OpenSSH_5.6p1.  **Work** runs CentOS 6.0 with OpenSSH_5.3p1.

**EDIT**: The solution glared straight at me as I came to work today.  [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) (a firewall) had been blocking my connections, and had cheerfully opened quite a few "Do you want to allow this connection" dialogues.  Thanks for the help; I'm granting @golimar the correct answer for this one, since it was a pretty plausible solution.

Comment: Are you sure that **outside** sees **work** as `work.example.com`? If **outside** is a firewall/proxy that's actually on the same internal network as **work**, then `work.example.com` may resolve differently depending of **outside** is resolving it, or **home** is resolving it. Run `nslookup work.example.com` on both **home** and **outside** and confirm that the IP returned is the same.

Comment: **Outside** does the resolving of **work**, and **home** doesn't have a clue who **work** is.  Anyway, since the port 80 example above works, that wouldn't have been a problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the options AllowTcpForwarding and/or GatewayPorts in the sshd_config file in "outside"

If that's the case, your ssh client should say something about it (in a log file or with the verbose option). I saw this in Putty on windows so I can't tell what the ssh command does...

Comment: Good advice, but no success I'm afraid.  I set both to yes and restarted sshd on "outside".  The ssh client connects ("Connection established") and tries to read files in .ssh (last entry: "debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1"), then it just hangs...